# Excel: Conditional formatting using COUNTIFS and AND

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to highlight values based on three criteria.

I have two sheets: one that has my detail (OVERVIEW) and one that I'm using as reference (LOOKUP).

```
**OVERVIEW (Sheet1)**
Column A contains DAY
Column B contains ACTIVITIES
If Monday is selected in column A choices are limited to ICT, Art or Music in column B

**LOOKUP (Sheet2)**
Column A contains DAYS
Column B contains ACTIVITIES
Column C contains PLACES

    A       B       C
1 Monday    ICT     6
2 Monday    Art     8
3 Monday    Music   16
4 Tuesday   Art     12
5 Tuesday   Science 10
3 Wednesday ICT     6
4 Wednesday Science 5
```

I've used Format Table for the LOOKUP sheet that uses an INDIRECT function so that when I use the OVERVIEW sheet I can choose DAY in column A and the relevant activity in column B

Is there a formula I can use for my OVERVIEW sheet that will highlight rows if they exceed criteria from my LOOKUP sheet?

i.e. [based on the example] If I have **7** (column C) entries that have both **Monday** (column A) and **ICT** (column B) then it will highlight the row.

I think I need to use a combination of COUNTIFS and AND but I'm unsure how to amalgamate them. Hope this makes sense to someone.

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different interpretation of the requirement. Please clear all conditional formatting (from `OVERVIEW`), select as many of the columns there as constitute your *row* width and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIFS(LOOKUP!$A:$A,$A1,LOOKUP!$B:$B,$B1)>INDEX(LOOKUP!$C:$C,MATCH($A1&"|"&$B1,LOOKUP!$E:$E,0))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select highlighting of choice <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

For the above to work (and I suspect one of us is making this much more complicated than really necessary) a helper column is required in `LOOKUP`, which I have above as ColumnE populated with:

```
 =A1&"|"&B1
```

copied down to suit.

Comment: Better late than never... I ended up using something akin to this; a separate sheet with a lookup column. Thanx.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `COUNTIFS` in the Conditional Formatting dialog.  `AND` is not needed since `COUNTIFS` will count the number of rows that match multiple criteria.

With your example, if you wanted to count rows where both:

- `Column A`=`"Monday"` ***and*** `Column B`=`"ICT"`

...then the formula would be:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Monday",B:B,"ICT")
```

---

If you want `Sheet 2, Row 1` to be highlighted based on the count of rows on `Sheet 1` where both `Column A`=`Sheet 2, A1` ***and*** `Column B`=`Sheet2, B1`, when the row count exceeds the number in `Sheet2, C1`...

1. On `Sheet 2`, click the heading for `Row 1`.
2. On the **Home** tab, click **Conditional Formatting**, then **New Rule**.
3. Click `Use a formula to determine which cells to format`.
4. In the `Format cells where this formula is true` box, enter or paste formula:

   =COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A$1,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet2!$B$1)>Sheet2!$C$1
5. Next click <kbd>Format</kbd>.
6. Go to the **Fill** tab and choose a colour and/or pattern.
7. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd> again.

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**COUNTIFS Worksheet Function** (Excel)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)
- Office.com : [**Use formulas with Conditional Formatting**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)